# Multiple Colons in CLASSPATH

Tags: java, linux, classpath

I am setting my classpath environment variable for java in Linux and in my existing classpath I noticed there are two occurrences of multiple colons in a row with no path between them.

EX) `/log4jpath.jar:/other/path.jar::/other/path2.jar:/other/path3.jar:::/other/final-path.jar`

Till seeing this I had never seen multiple colons between entries. Is this similar to if you add a trailing colon for the current directory? Will this cause an issue (in an unworking state currently so have not been able to try) or is this just bad syntax?

Comment: It is a mistake. It means nothing. You can collapse them all to a single colon.

Comment: Agreed, but on this system I am not allowed to change the classpath, only append things to it. So I wanted to verify that they will not cause any issues and was curious if they add the current working directory of whatever code/script is using the classpath.